# Google-Bigquery: Conflicting field names on JOIN?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having a problem with the following JOIN:

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id
  FROM tables.table_a as a
  JOIN tables.table_b as b
    ON a.id = b.id
```

This seems pretty basic to me, but despite the `a.` and `b.` prefixes I'm getting the following error message:

> **Error:** Conflicting names in JOIN output: field id is present in both side of the JOIN.

Is this behavior known?

Comment: Please provide the full syntax, something is odd how you wrote your query.

Comment: Hmmm.. I ran the *exact same* query again this morning without any problems. Strange.

Comment: If you can get a repro: please include the job id of a failing query (or the project id and approximate timestamp of when you started the query) and we can investigate what happened from BigQuery's perspective. Cheers!

Comment: did you try on a_id = b_id (perhaps its looking for the alias). Otherwise it looks fine and we can help you more if you paste the actual query.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon I ran into the same issue again.. turned to google and found my own question again haha. This time, though, I do have job ID that you might want to investigate.. How could I send this to you?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and resolved it by checking the "flatten results" box in the hidden options when writing to a table.

Comment: I don't know why this got down vote! It actually solved my problem by enabling flatten results in Big Query console. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Though it should be noted that this is a workaround that only works if you don't mind flattening the result table. Otherwise, you would need to "unflatten" the results by doing a `GROUP BY` combined with a `NEST` aggregation. Still, it does allow me to get past the issue for now.